# Android background service get killed eventhough it has return START_STICKY in it

Tags: android, android-intent, service, background-service

One of the requirements in the app that I am developing is "show something on the screen on event." Basically, I made a background service and in that, I catch the screen on intent and pass it to a `BroadcastReceiver`. Then, in the receiver, I open an activity and "show something". However, on Android 7-8. I think the background service get killed over a night because the next day my service is not catching anything and my receiver is not receiving. I even ask for the

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>
```

permission, and override it, but the service still gets killed. You can find my `Service` class, `Receiver` class, and manifest below.

Service class

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;

import android.util.Log;

public class Services extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "Services";

    private BroadcastReceiver sReceiver;

    public static final String ALARM_ALERT_ACTION = "com.android.deskclock.ALARM_ALERT";

    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg) {
        return null;
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flag, int startIs) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand: " + this.toString() + " sReceiver = " + sReceiver);
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
            filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
            filter.addAction(ALARM_ALERT_ACTION);
            sReceiver = new Receivers(new Handler());
            registerReceiver(sReceiver, filter);
            if(intent != null){
                LUtil.appendToLogs("Service onStartCommand " + intent.getAction() + " intent catched.");
            }
            return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(sReceiver);

    }
}
```

Receiver class:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;

import com.mytoz.app.object.CommercialData;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Receivers extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "Receivers";
    private final Handler handler;

    public Receivers(Handler handler) {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onReceive: id = " + this.toString());
        Log.i(TAG, "intent.getAction() " + intent.getAction());

        LUtil.appendToLogs("onReceive " + intent.getAction() + " intent passed to receiver.");

        if(LUtil.isPowerOff){
            LUtil.isPowerOff = false;
            return;
        }

        if (intent.getAction() != null) {
            if(intent.getAction().equals(Services.ALARM_ALERT_ACTION)){
                LUtil.lastAlarmAlert = System.currentTimeMillis();
                Log.i(TAG, "onReceive: LUtil.lastAlarmAlert = " + LUtil.lastAlarmAlert);
                return;
            }
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {

                AudioManager am = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                final int mode = am.getMode();
                if (AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL == mode) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onReceive: in call");
                    // device is in a telephony call
                } else if (AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION == mode) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onReceive: commuunication");
                    // device is in communiation mode, i.e. in a VoIP or video call
                } else if (AudioManager.MODE_RINGTONE == mode) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onReceive: ringtone");

                    // device is in ringing mode, some incoming is being signalled
                } else {
                    // SHOW SOMETHING
                }

            } else {


            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>



    <application xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/app_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/app_logo"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:hardwareAccelerated"
        android:name=".Mytoz">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
            android:value="false" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>

        <service android:name=".Services" />
        <service
            android:exported="false"
            android:name=".FirebaseJobService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.firebase.jobdispatcher.ACTION_EXECUTE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name=".PushHandleService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:name=".BootCompletedReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>

        <receiver
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:name=".UpdateReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme" android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".networking.CrashReportHandle" />
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name=".CommercialVideo" android:taskAffinity=".CommercialVideo" android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:launchMode="singleTop"/>

        <activity android:name=".ShopActivity" android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name=".InterestActivity" android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SignUpActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" />
        <activity android:name=".MyAdsActivity" android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name=".SignUpThirdActivity" android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name=".SignUpSecondActivity" android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name=".SettingsFirstActivity" android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name=".SettingsSecondActivity" android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name=".SettingsThirdActivity" android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name=".ItemDetailActivity" android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name=".CheckoutActivity" android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name=".DeliveryActivity" android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name="com.braintreepayments.api.BraintreeBrowserSwitchActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="${applicationId}.braintree" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".PaymentActivity" android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name=".CreditCardActivity" android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name=".OfferActivity" android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name=".ConfirmationActivity" android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name=".AdsSecondActivity" android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name=".CustomAdsVideoActivity" android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name=".OrderActivity" android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name=".OrderDetailsActivity" android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SmartyAdsActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: `START_STICKY` has nothing to do with keeping service alive. You need a foreground service if you want it to run in background without being killed

Comment: also check the device's memory. the device's memory could have been low making your service get killed by the system

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko even tried the foreground service too, it will stop automatically in 8.0 within 10 mins.

Comment: you likely implemented it incorrectly, as I am using it, and it runs *forever* for me on Android 8

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko some of the manufacturer who customizes native os like (oppo, vivo, xiaomi, samsung) they have a clear option so when service stops automatically even we start the service at foreground service is that any possible way to prevent this one?

Comment: @RamSuthakar if you say that it is an *option*, then it is up to the user to choose if he wants to stop the service, or not, and it is OK.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko okay it may be a option but implemented as per the google doc only https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Foreground but cannt able to get the alive service more than 10 mins tried 5 more diff devices, if you have find any good explames suggest to solve

Comment: @RamSuthakar, I just followed google's docs, likely the page you have linked. I still think you did something wrong while implementing it

Comment: I dont get it apps like whatsapp's facebook's skype's background services are always up and running. Never to be killed. How they implement and their services are not killed?

Comment: @RamSuthakar first I have the same problem with background service after 10 mins the service was killed, with 
`<uses-permission       android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>` this permission I make it to stay for a day..

Comment: @TimBlack will try this one

Comment: @TimBlack tried android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/> this one in my case but it will stop automatically within 10 mins :(

Comment: @Ram Suthakar you need to ask the user to disable it :) only permission is not going to work :)

Comment: @TimBlack tried that code mate, check this link https://i.imgur.com/aGArdlH.png, can you suggest me any sample for example to solve this one